# Construct an std:array from a smaller std::array

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a template class defining the number of elements in an internal `std::array`. How would I construct a new object from a larger object. So far I have the copy constructors defined but these do not compile as there is no proper constructor for `std::array` with different sizes.

The current class definition:

```cpp
template<uint32_t MAX_LENGTH>
class A 
{
  A() = default;
  ~A() override = default;

  A(const A<MAX_LENGTH>& rhs) :
    current_length_(rhs.get_length()),
    data(rhs.get_data_const())
  { }

  template<uint32_t MAX_LENGTH_RHS, std::enable_if_t<(MAX_LENGTH_RHS < MAX_LENGTH), int> = 0>
  A(const A<MAX_LENGTH_RHS>& rhs) :
    current_length_(rhs.get_length()),
    data(rhs.get_data_const())
  { }

  template<uint32_t MAX_LENGTH_RHS, std::enable_if_t<(MAX_LENGTH_RHS < MAX_LENGTH), int> = 0>
  A(const A<MAX_LENGTH_RHS>&& rhs) :
    data(rhs.get_data_const())
  { }

  const std::array<int, MAX_LENGTH>& get_data_const() const { return data; }
 
  private:
    std::array<int, MAX_LENGTH> data;
}
```

What I would like to compile:

```cpp
A<5> a5;
// Set some data in a5.

// Next copy construct a larger object and set the data from a5 in it.
A<10> a10(a5);
```

As This fails with the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::array<10>::array(const std::array<5>&)’
   5 |         data_(rhs.get_data_const())
```

So how do I initialize an `std::array` in the copy constructor initialiser list when the size of the source object is smaller?

Comment: Please add the error message you get when you try this. Also, you could just do a manual `std::copy` of the array's contents in the constructor.

Comment: @cigien Good point, added it.

Comment: You would probably be better off creating a template standalone function, and ensure that the destination `std::array` is large enough to hold the data you're copying to.  By the time you get to all the corner cases, a standalone function would seem to be much easier to handle.  Right now, I don't see where you're making these types of checks.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie is the `std::enable_if_t` not covering those?

Comment: Ok, I didn't see the `enable_if`.  But you mention "copy constructor", but what you have is not really a copy constructor.  It is a constructor, but not a copy constructor.  A copy constructor would have a type that is the exact class type being copied to.  A `std::array<int, 4>` is not the same type as a `std::array<int, 3>`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Agree, the copy constructor is just the first function after the destructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something somewhat straight forward like this instead of the copy constructor you've got:

```
  template<uint32_t MAX_LENGTH_RHS, /*enable_if...*/>
  A(const A<MAX_LENGTH_RHS>& rhs) {
      const auto& rhs_data = rhs.get_data_const();
      std::copy(rhs_data.begin(), rhs_data.end(), data.begin());
  }
```

Comment: Or `std::copy` instead of a loop.

Comment: Yes that would work, I was hoping for something without a loop.

Comment: `rhs_data` probably needs to be a const reference.

Comment: Seems like`std::copy` it will be. I do have a gut feeling the && version is not ideal for this but, always a next ticket to make something even better.